# PostgreSQL insert if foreign key exists

Tags: postgresql

How can I insert a new row in a table with a foreign key reference only if the foreign key (in this case model) exists?

Currently I have the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO furniture (model, type) VALUES (modelA, chair)
```

Comment: `... WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM models WHERE model = modelA)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a SELECT that returns nothing if the FK does not exist.

```
INSERT INTO furniture (model, type) 
select 'modelA', 'chair'
where exists (select * 
              from model 
              where model.model = 'modelA');
```

You did not tell us what the referenced table is called. I assumed it's `model` - you need to adjust that to the real names.

Comment: you may also want to add locking to the exists clause to avoid race conditions
see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/252925