# PostgreSQL insert multiple values if foreign key exists

Tags: postgresql

Given:

1. Table A with multiple rows and attributes: (*A_attr1* (key) , A_attr2).
2. Table B with attributes (*B_attr1* (key) , *A_attr1* (foreign key), B_attr2).

How do I insert some values in the table B **only if the foreign key exists**?

Comment: If the rows to be inserted are coming from a query or a table, then a simple join will filter out rows that do not have a match in the related table. Thus, the insert will only include the matching rows.

Comment: Your question is somewhat ambiguous as you do not define what *only if foreign key exists* actually means. Presumably that means the column `A_attr1` must exist in `Table A` before being inserted onto `Table_B`. This is well covered in the answers. The other condition is that `A_attr1` is not provided in the insert to `Table_b`. This condition is covered by a `not null` constraint on Table_B.A_attr1.

Comment: In the post is not specified but the data of Table_A was already present and we wanted to insert new data in Table_B from a dataset that contained both wrong (not present) and correct (present) values of A_attr1. We wanted to insert only the tuples in which A_attr1 was present in Table_A

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, we can use the `Where Exists` to implement your use case.

Here is an example of using it.

```
Insert Into Table_B Select 'Value 1', 'Foreign Value', 'Value 2' Where Exists 
(Select 1 From Table_A Where A_attr1 = 'Foreign Value');
```

This will insert only if the `"Foreign Value"` is present in Table_A.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to consider the fact that the **condition** (existence of foreign key in table A)  **is fundamental**, in fact, if we try to add values in Table_B with an *A_attr1* that it doesn't exist in Table_A we get an error of this type:

```
ERROR: the INSERT or the UPDATE on the TABLE table_B violates the foreign key constraint
"_A_attr1_"
DETAIL: the key (A_attr1)=(wrong_value) it's not present in the table "Table_A"
```

This is a possible solution:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B(B_attr1, A_attr1, B_attr2)
SELECT x.*
FROM (VALUES 

(something,something_else, something_else2),
(something_else3,something_else4, something_else5),
...
(something_else20, something_else21,something_else22)
) x(B_attr1, A_attr1, B_attr2)

WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT FROM TABLE_A y 
WHERE (y.A_attr1)=(x.A_attr1)
FOR SHARE);
```

The result is the **addition in B of all the tuples that are acceptable** (that is the one with the existing foreign keys).

This post is an extension of the following question:
[PostgreSQL insert if foreign key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224438/postgresql-insert-if-foreign-key-exists)

The solution is based on the comments on this post:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252875/how-to-make-on-conflict-work-for-compound-foreign-key-columns/252925#252925

Comment: Sort of fundamental. You can enter a row in the child table(B) that has `NULL` for the  `A_attr1 (foreign key)` and it will succeed with the default action of `MATCH SIMPLE` per [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html). So you can have child records that don't match on a parent record FK. Adding a `NOT NULL` to the child FK referencing column deals with that.

Comment: Why don't you just post an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224438/postgresql-insert-if-foreign-key-exists instead of re-asking the question?

Comment: Could have done that, i thought it was more clear this way.

Comment: The problem was adding a tuple B with an A_attr1 not present in Table_A and therefore i didn't need it.